# The textarea disappears - Ckeditor

Tags: textarea, ckeditor

I try to use the ckeditor but if I put e.g. the colorbutton plugin, the textarea disappears.
Here is how I tried:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                extraPlugins: 'colorbutton',
            } );
```

I tried other plugin but it was OK.

The colorbutton plugin works fine if I try to put only a file which is only a form with a textarea.
But the above I try to put in my site where are a more complex form and after that, the textarea disappears...

why? Something wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using CKEditor 4?

If yes, then there is a chance that the colorbutton plugin (or one of its dependencies) is simply missing in your package.

Check what errors do you have in Firebug. Is the plugin is missing, you should see something like

```
[CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "colorbutton" was not found
```

Comment: Yes, CKEditor4. There is no problem issue with the version as I said above, if only a textarea and the ckeditor is in the .html file, the colorbutton plugin works fine. but it does not work in the original content. And I dont know why... Other plugins works fine (however I tried only with 2-3). May I will try with a similar plugin

Comment: Check Firebug and/or other JavaScript error console (e.g in Chrome) to see what JS errors are reported.

Comment: Firefox Developer tools say: "panelbutton" was not found. So I downloaded it, and now everything works fine :)

Comment: The best solution for this kind of issues is to build your own package @ http://ckeditor.com/builder 
If you add the colorbutton plugin there, all dependencies will be added automatically for you. Because all selected plugins are merged into ckeditor.js the editor will also load faster thanks to reduced number of HTTP requests.